# Azure Node EPERM on symlinks for local module

Tags: node.js, azure

I'm trying to deploy a node server on azure using local git repository. The node version is 8.0.0 and npm 5.0.0.

I have a local module in the repository that is required by the server. When installed npm creates a symlink in the node_modules to the actual module folder. Locally that works fine, but on azure it seems I'm not allowed to create symlinks, thus getting a EPERM 'symlink' error when deploying.

Is there a workaround for this? A way to either avoid symlinks, or get permission to create them?

### UPDATE

I was able to get the server running by using powershell console on azure and copying the folder instead of creating a symlink to it. Still in need of a better solution

Comment: Could you provide the `package.json` file which you are using?

Comment: It's pretty standard, except for the local module:
` "dependencies": { ... "xclinicapi": "file:xclinic" ... } `

Comment: @IvoUdelsmann did you manage to find a solution for this on Azure?